# Can't get a forked repo clean of any changes i made

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project on Github.  I cloned and forked the repo to my computer.  I have made some changes.  I then pushed these changes to my forked repo.  I want to get a copy of the original repository without any changes that i have made.  Basically, I want a copy of the original "clean" from anything i did.

Ideas?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` show?

Answer (score 0):

This will put you on a branch using the code from your initial commit:

```
git clone <repo>
git checkout -b initial_state <sha_of_initial_commit>
```

Check `git log` to find the sha code from your initial commit:

`git log --pretty=oneline  master | tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

Add the repository that you forked from (often called the *upstream*) as a remote:

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com/...
```

Then, fetch from it and create a branch at upstream's master:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b original upstream/master
```

If there's been additional work done on the upstream since you forked it, you can use:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph upstream/master master
```

To see where the two branches split, and create `original` at the SHA where they diverge, instead.